# ewma or shift of MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

If I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex` where the first level is symbol, the second level is a date, what is the easiest way to perform an `ewma` or a `shift` operation on the data.

Currently naively shifting shifts across the symbols.

Perhaps I need to use a `Panel`?

Using:

```
In [13]: pd.concat({"GOOG": pd.DataFrame({'price':[100,101]},index=["2013-1-1","2013-1-2"]),"AAPL": pd.DataFrame({'price':[100,101]},index=pd.to_datetime(["2013-1-1","2013-1-2"]))}, axis=0, names=["Symbol", "Date"])
Out[13]:
                 price
Symbol Date
AAPL   2013-1-1    100
       2013-1-2    101
GOOG   2013-1-1    100
       2013-1-2    101

In [17]: df.shift()
Out[17]:
                 price
Symbol Date
AAPL   2013-1-1    NaN
       2013-1-2    100
GOOG   2013-1-1    101
       2013-1-2    100
```

This looks like it might work, but the `Panel` layout is definitely not intuitive:
`df.to_panel().shift(1, axis="minor").ix["price"]`

Answer (score 2):

use `groupby()`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform("shift")
```

Comment: That works. The `ewma` case can be solved similarly: `df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x, com=2))`